# Passing an array in url data var

Tags: jquery, arrays, url

I am trying to pass an array via the data var of an href link:

```
<a href="#" class="edit" data-myvar="<?php echo json_encode($row); ?>">Test</a>
```

I am using Jquery to process the variable:

```
$(function(){

     $('.edit').click(function(){

          var res=jQuery.parseJSON($(this).data("myvar"));

      console.log(res);

});


});
```

The console log says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: To get that error you have to pass nothing into the parse function.  Do a console.log of `$(this).data("myvar")` and see what that returns :)

Comment: Show us the actual rendered HTML, not with php tags in it, and we can help.  It's the value that's in data-myvar that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, apply [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php) in your `json_encode()` call to ensure that all quotes are okay in HTML.

jQuery already does JSON parsing on `data-` attributes for you, if it contains valid JSON syntax. So doing the following is the right way of doing it:

```
// this will contain the JSON presentation of $row variable from PHP.    
var res = $(this).data("myvar");
```

From the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A value
>   is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's
>   representation. For example, "1E02" and "100.000" are equivalent as
>   numbers (numeric value 100) but converting them would alter their
>   representation so they are left as strings. The string value "100" is
>   converted to the number 100.
>
> **When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array
>   (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string**;
>   it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If
>   the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a
>   string.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3tbF/)

Comment: ok I removed the json encode used within the HTML. Now when I try to access the array: res["user_id"]=undefined, res[0]=A, res[1]=r... and so on.. I'm confused

Comment: You don't remove `json_encode()`, you remove `$.parseJSON`, which is done internally by jQuery itself.

Comment: I have also enhanced my answer to better clarify future readers about this.

Comment: I had already trried your suggestion, using json_encode on the html side and NOT using $.parseJSON. now my output is "undefined" for the 3 examples I provided above!

Comment: So check the contents of your `$row` variable.

Comment: I already did that too, if I view the html this is what the href looks like: <a href="#" class="edit" data-myvar="{"0":"1","user_id":"1","1":"John","first_name":"John","2":"Smith","second_name":"Smith"}">

Comment: Thanks but your fiddle gives an empty console output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37465/discussion-between-gustavohenke-and-alan-a)

Comment: The key is to use html entites and json encode on the html and there is no need to parse the json within the jquery!

Answer (score 1):

You never declare a variable:

```
var jQuery.parseJSON(res=$(this).data("myvar"));
                     ^ Not how to declare a variable
```

Should be:

```
var res = jQuery.parseJSON($(this).data("myvar"));
```

Comment: I have corrected my code, that was an error I made when making my post, the problem still exists with the correction

Comment: @AlanA -- You're also spelling `edit` wrong in your click handler. Also, what line is the error occurring on?

Comment: Apologies 'edit' was a typo, my original code was spelt correctly